# when v-model is null, set checkbox value to be false in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

In the following vue.js example, if the value of `myBool` is `null`, checkbox doesn't return `N`.

```
<input v-model="myBool" true-value="Y" false-value="N" type="checkbox">
```

However, if I set `myBool` to `false`, checkbox returns `N`. How can I get the value `N` even though `myBool` is `null`?
I don't want to manually check the return value of the checkbox, then add a logic to make it false. Is there any better way to get the `N` value when `myBool` is `null`?

Comment: What do you mean the "checkbox returns `N`"? When you set `myBool` to `false`, what is getting set to `"N"`?

Comment: its called false-value="N" not null-value="N". This seems like expected behavior to me

Comment: @thanksd, when `myBool` is set to false, myBool becomes `N`.

Comment: @victor, how can I make the null-value to be `N` ?

Comment: What do you mean? When `myBool` is set to `false`, `myBool` becomes `false`: https://jsfiddle.net/oayc4pv5/

Comment: @thanksd, keep checking and un-checking the checkbox, you will see the value becomes either Y or N.

Comment: But that does not set `myBool` to `false`. That is setting the value of `myBool` to either `"Y"` or `"N"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this out, but maybe set v-model to a [Computed Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

```js
computed: {
  myBoolComputed: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.myBool ? true : false
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newValue) {
      this.myBool = newValue
      // or if preferred to stay strictly Boolean
      // this.myBool = (newValue === 'Y')
    }
  }
}
```

The template

```html
<input v-model="myBoolComputed" true-value="Y" false-value="N" type="checkbox">
```